# Persisting Session State via multiple request using jQuery $.ajax()

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery, callback

just been trying to recieve the session value from multiple jquery ajax requests on the same domain name. i think i understand that each request is kind of a virtual browser request so the session is mutally exclusive to each request, but there must be a way some how, has anyone solved this. Basically this is what im trying to do:

I have tries using type: GET and POST but still no luck.

Can anyone help please, Thanks?

First request - Stores the product id in a session

$.ajax({

```
    url: 'http://localhost/websitetest/test.aspx?storeproduct=' + productid,
    type: 'GET',  
    async: true,
    success: function(data) {
    }
```

});

Second Request - From the callback variable "data" recieves the product id from the session

```
$.ajax({

    url: 'http://localhost/websitetest/test.aspx,
    type: 'GET',  
    async: true,
    success: function(data) {
          var productID = data;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no question to send ajax request while accessing Session variable from asp page.

Simply you can do is :

```
<%
String session_var = Session("name_of_session_variable");
%>
```

Even if you still want to try Ajax, I think you will need to print the session variable in test.aspx file using Response.Write(), which will automatically return the content.

Please check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/ASP/asp_sessions.asp) for further reference.

Please correct me as well if I am wrong.

Thank you.